# Visual Studio ASP Development Server and PHP

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-development-serv

Hi all I am currently looking into developing a Silverlight app which needs access to PHP scripts. Visual Studio is launching the ASP Development Server but does not support PHP script handling. Is there a way that I can configure the development server to accept or PHP or make visual studio develop from own local Apache server that can support PHP.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and install IIS Express, which is a lightweight and stand-alone edition of IIS that works as a replacement for the development server. Most likely you can install a PHP module for it to allow it to run PHP scripts (this is as far as I can remember also available in the Web Platform Installer).

Comment: Will installing IIS express affect the Apache Server I currently have installed or will I need to uninstall Apache to install IIS

Comment: IIS Express is completely isolated and will not affect any other program you've got installed, except maybe earlier versions of itself.